# Receiving main photos

Tags: pandas, image, hyperlink

I managed to get pandas table made from wikipedia links. Im just wondering how can i get the first photo of the topic from every each link.

The photo can be placed in separate table or in the first as well.

So here is the code and I dont know how to go next

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

starter_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mammal_common_names'

r = requests.get(starter_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'firstHeading'})

data = []

for link in set(soup.select('a[href^="/wiki/"]')):
    data.append({
        'source url':starter_url,
        'source title':title,
        'link url':link['href'],
        'link title':link.text
    })


pd.DataFrame(data)#.to_csv('WebCrawler.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```